# How do I dispatch the a keyboard event with the keycode 81 automatically?

Tags: javascript, keycode, dispatchevent

If you use the repl link, Click apes, and then click begin with undefined, you'll see a timer of my first div, #shrimpCook01, start.
If you press the letter q twice the timer of second div, #shrimpCook02, will start.
The objective is two start the timer of the second div when the first div starts by dispatching a keydown event.
The code I have I think is close, but it is not completing this objective. Maybe I'm missing a keyup as well?

[Objective-start timer of #shrimpCook02](https://repl.it/@MathewStratton1/CostlyHumongousAddress#index.php)

```js
var element = document.createElement("p");
element.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'q'}));
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'q'}));
console.log(e.key);
```

Comment: Curious, why do you need to dispatch an event? For example, why can't you call a function to start the timer?

Comment: @Adam I figured it an easy way to do so, and for future reference so that I can learn how to emulate a keyboard key without touching the keyboard.

Comment: @MisterJojo don't think that is completely true I think there is a possible way

Comment: @MisterJojo well maybe you can answer this for me otherwise Ill have to ask another question. I have my code set on an interval to update the innerHTML of both divs, but only shrimpCook01's timer variable, time01, is updating. shrimpCook02's timer variable, time02 is not. Do you know how to update timer02 and then update the innerHTML of shrimpcook02 like that of shrimpCook01?

Comment: you are talking about 265 lines of code and a couple of time to assimilate it. Make it Minimal and Reproducible  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example